# Using SELECT part in OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, outer-join

This is my SQL-query:

```
SELECT 
    b.MaakArtikel, 
    b.Bewerking,
    [pp].dbo.WORKINGDAYADD('2013-06-27 00:00:00.000',0-b.Startdag_backwards) AS Startdatum, 
    i.Class_06 AS Afdeling, 
    b.Minuten*10+ISNULL(br.Tijd,0) AS Minuten, 
    1+ISNULL(br.Orders,0) AS Aantal 
FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEWERKINGSTRUCTUUR b 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [211].dbo.Items i 
        ON b.MaakArtikel = i.ItemCode 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW br 
        ON [pp].dbo.WORKINGDAYADD('2013-06-27 00:00:00.000',0-b.Startdag_backwards) = br.Start 
        AND i.Class_06 = br.Afdeling 
WHERE MaakArtikel = 'HT 10.038'
```

The query works properly, but it's a little bit slow. That's because of my second `OUTER JOIN`. I have to join the view by `Startdatum` (that's selected at line 4). As it is not a real column name, I can't use it directly in my `OUTER JOIN`. That means that the function `[pp].dbo.WORKINGDAYADD()` has to be triggered twice (once in my selection which is not a problem, and once in my `OUTER JOIN` which is double work).

I could write a stored procedure and use the result of function `[pp].dbo.WORKINGDAYADD()` in a variable, but that is not disireable. Is there a way to use Startdatum in my `OUTER JOIN` expression? Or do I really have to use a stored procedure for this?

Comment: What table does `Startdag_backwards` come from?

Comment: @yvytty You mean to join it with a real column? That's because there is no real column with that value, I have to calculate the right date en then join on it

Comment: @GarethD `Startdag_backwards` comes from `[pp].dbo.VW_BEWERKINGSTRUCTUUR`, I will edit my post and add some aliasses to make this clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just move the function to a subquery, as below:

```
SELECT  MaakArtikel, 
        Bewerking,
        b.Startdatum, 
        i.Class_06 AS Afdeling, 
        Minuten * 10 + ISNULL(br.Tijd,0) AS Minuten, 
        1 + ISNULL(br.Orders, 0) AS Aantal 
FROM    (   SELECT  *, 
                    StartDatum = [pp].dbo.WORKINGDAYADD('2013-06-27 00:00:00.000', 0 - Startdag_backwards)
            FROM    [pp].dbo.VW_BEWERKINGSTRUCTUUR b 
        ) b
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [211].dbo.Items i 
            ON b.MaakArtikel = i.ItemCode 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW br 
            ON b.Startdatum = br.Start 
            AND i.Class_06 = br.Afdeling 
WHERE   MaakArtikel = 'HT 10.038';
```

**NOTE**

I do not condone using `SELECT *`, and in your working query you should replace this with just the columns you need from `[pp].dbo.VW_BEWERKINGSTRUCTUUR`.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing your results of

```
[pp].dbo.WORKINGDAYADD('2013-06-27 00:00:00.000',0-Startdag_backwards) AS Startdatum
```

Into a SQL Variable

```
DECLARE @myVariable DATETIME
SET @myVariable = [pp].dbo.WORKINGDAYADD('2013-06-27 00:00:00.000',0-Startdag_backwards)
```

Then on your outer join do this

```
ON @myVariable = br.Start
```

Or something to that effect.
Bobby

Answer (score 0):

You can store the output of `[pp].dbo.WORKINGDAYADD()` in a variable then use the variable in the code.
(I assume the result data type of the function is datetime..)

```
DECLARE @StartDatum datetime
SET @StartDatum = ([pp].dbo.WORKINGDAYADD('2013-06-27 00:00:00.000',0-Startdag_backwards))

SELECT 
    MaakArtikel, 
    Bewerking,
    @StartDatum, 
    i.Class_06 AS Afdeling, 
    Minuten*10+ISNULL(br.Tijd,0) AS Minuten, 
    1+ISNULL(br.Orders,0) AS Aantal 
FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEWERKINGSTRUCTUUR b 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [211].dbo.Items i 
        ON b.MaakArtikel = i.ItemCode 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW br 
        ON br.Start = @StartDatum 
        AND i.Class_06 = br.Afdeling 
WHERE MaakArtikel = 'HT 10.038'
```